# ¿Cómo crear un carrusel de imágenes al estilo de la pantalla de inicio de sesión de Tinder?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

En algunas apps, y la más conocida Tinder, el `login screen` tiene un carrusel de imágenes para promocionar la app o como tutorial.

¿Cómo se puede hacer este carrusel?. He buscado librerías en github pero tengo algunos problemas para encontrarlas.

¿Esta interfaz tiene algún nombre? me gustan con esos tres círculos grises. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba Appintro https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit** 
El nombre correcto para llamarlas es `OnBoarding` y no como las llamaba `welcomeScreen`

Recomiendo la librería [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) su implementación es lo más sencillo, puedes personalizar la `onBoarding` a tu gusto, algunas propiedades que puedes personalizar:

- Titulo
- Descripción
- Foto
- Aspecto de los botones
- Texto de los botones
- Color de los indicadores
- Animación de transición entre vistas
- Petición de los permisos en tiempo de ejecución de `Android M`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo quieres hacer manualmente así no tener que depender de la libreria:

Sigue ese [tuto](http://blog.grafixartist.com/onboarding-android-viewpager-google-way/) o [ese](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/creating-onboarding-screens-for-android-apps--cms-24465) 
Otro librería [Material Intro Screen](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen) y aquí su [tutorial](https://medium.com/tangoagency/material-intro-screen-for-android-apps-c4317fbac923#.l94uxtxmq)

Comment: Me encantó el descubrimiento de esta libreria , ¡gracias!

Answer (score 4):

La verdad esque si lo analizas, la presentación/carrousel es simplemente un album de imagenes con el indicador de número de paginas.

Para lograrlo puedes usar [Jake's ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

---

## Uso

([Ejemplo traducido de su web](http://viewpagerindicator.com/))

Incluye uno de los widgets en tu vista.

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

En el metodo onCreate (de la vista o el fragmento) enlaza el indicador al  `ViewPager`.

```
//Set the pager with an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

//Bind the title indicator to the adapter
TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

(Opcional) si tienes que usar un `OnPageChangeListener` con el paginador de la vista tienes que debes asignarlo al indicador mejor que al paginador

```
//continued from above
titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);
```

[Encuentra más ejemplos en el repo de github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample)

Answer (score 2):

Los puedes hacer con un `View Pager` e implementar el código a tu manera.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] flag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);

        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

        country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
                "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
                "Russia", "Japan" };

        population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
                "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
                R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
                R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
                R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country, population, flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Consulta todo el código en: 
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Espero te sirva algo así. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Justo aquí está un link sobre lo que buscas además de que puedes encontrar muchos widgets que podrían ser de gran ayuda.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/2731